# cant call the web service from html page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to call an asp.net web service from an html page,but its not able to call the web service .but instead its open the url for the webservice only..

I tried to call it from the FORM in html on action="web service link and method ="POST":

```
<form id="getdata"  method="post" action="192.168.1.1:85/Service.asmx?op=Hello" target="_blank">

    <input id="btnload" type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

ERROR ITS SHOWS:

> The webpage at 192.168.1.1:85/Service.asmx?op=Hello might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   Error code: ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Web service is working fine and tested.
pls help.....

Answer (score 1):

Your `action=""` attribute needs to specify the URI scheme because it isn't a relative URI.

Use this:

```
action="http://192.168.1.1:85/Service.asmx?op=Hello"
```

---

In a URI, the scheme (often incorrectly called "the protocol") is the first part before the colon which states what type of URI it is, for example:

```
mailto:foo@bar.com
http://hostname:8080/path
file://\\SMBServer\share\path
urn:epc:tag:cpi-var:3.0614141.5PQ7%2FZ43.12345
```

Comment: is thier any other method to call a web service from html ..tried all the post on net but none succeded

Comment: @PIYUSHRANA The other main approach is to use JavaScript with `XMLHttpRequest` - aka "AJAX".

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.support.cors = true;
     function fun() {
         $.ajax({
             crossDomain: true,
             type: "POST",
             url: "`http://192.168.1.1:85/Service.asmx?op=Hello`",
             data: "", 
             dataType: "text", 
             success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
                           },
             error: function (error) {
                 alert(error.error());
             }
         });
         }         
    </script>always give error: as Object object 
error as: No transport available